# php: check if a file is open

Tags: php, file

I'm writing a document managment system. One of the features that has been requested is that users be able to cause the system to copy certain files to a location that both the users and php have access to. From here the user will be able to directly edit the files. What needs to happen is that the edited file must be automatically saved to the document management system as a new version. My question is with regards to this last point.

I have a page that allows the user to view all versions of a specific file. I was thinking that what would be cool would be to have things that when this page is accessed by anyone then php checks if there is an associated file that was edited and is now closed and simply move it to the right place and give it version info. Would this be possible? For example if a user is editing a file using MS Word, would php be able to know if that file is in use? If yes, how?

Another alternative is to just grab all files that were edited periodically (during the witching hour, for example) and also have a handy 'synchronise' button that users can click to signal that they are done.

here's some stuff I've tried:
flock: i thought it mich return false for files that are in use. mistaken
fstat: doesn't return anything useful as far as I can tell
unlink: I thought I might make a copy of the file then try unlink the original(user edited one). it turns out unlink works on stuff that is open

any ideas?

Also, it needs to work on windows and linux...

Here's some clarification for them what need: if andrew were to click the 'edit' button corresponding to a word file then the word file would be copied to some location. Andrew would then edit it using MS word, save his changes (possible more than once) and close it. That is all I want Andrew to do. I want my code to see that the file is closed then do stuff with it

Comment: To check the file, PHP file modify time function                  date ("Y-m-d.", filemtime('filename.doc'))

Comment: the modified time was when it was modified, not closed. usually people save as they close things but I cant ever be sure that they didn't save stuff without editing

Comment: Did you use `flock` with `LOCK_EX`?

Comment: without editing, Save the file.. to give modify time that function

Answer (score 3):

You can create a file "filename.lock" (or "filename.lck") for each file open.
And you delete the file "filename.lock" (or "filename.lck") when is unlock.

And you can check if file is locked when the file "filename.lock" (or "filename.lck") exists.

Comment: upped again. don't know who downed this one and why (a comment would be helpful!), but this isn't such a bad solution. It is even used a lot on unix os's by several systems

Comment: how can i get every file processing program (eg: word, notepad, open office stuff, etc) to delete the .lock files for me? As far as I can see this is impossible to pull off, the user gets to open the file however they want. That's the crux of the problem really...

Comment: The best method to remove the lock after it has been closed is to unset the "filename.lck" file in PHP which would remove the file from the directory. `fclose($myOpenedFile); unset($mylockfile);`

Answer (score 2):

If you're running under unix OS, you can implement a strategy like that:

1. Write a bash script like this `lsof | grep /absolute/path/to/file.txt`

   You can also parameterize that
2. Recall that script from php

`<?php
$result=shell_exec("myScriptPath");
echo($result);
?>`

Remember that bash script will return status 0 if no one has file open, 256 (1) otherwise